# how to apply reset button selected value

Tags: javascript, php

code is php dynamic, how to aplly reset button i am applying many more step please help me this right or wrong and how to right way say me.
code is php dynamic, how to aplly reset button i am applying many more step please help me this right or wrong and how to right way say me.

```
<div style="margin-top:2%;display:none; " id="filt_box" id="reset">    
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
        <label for="filter_seller_user">Sellers</label>
        <select class="form-control-dropdown" id="filter_seller_user" name="filter_seller_user[]" 
         multiple="multiple">           
          @foreach($seller_user as $key=>$value)
            <option value="{{$value->id}}">{{$value->name}}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
        <label for="filter_generated_by_user">Generated By</label>
        <select class="form-control-dropdown" id="filter_generated_by_user" 
          name="filter_generated_by_user[]" multiple="multiple">
          @foreach($clients_user as $key=>$value)
            <option value="clients_user-{{$value->id}}">{{$value->name}}</option>
          @endforeach
          @foreach($main_clients_user as $key=>$value)
            <option value="main_clients_user-{{$value->id}}">{{$value->name}}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
        <label for="filter_generated_by_user">Business Name</label>
        <input type="tetx" name="filter_business_name" id="filter_business_name" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 div_btn">
      <div id="err_date" class="text-danger"></div>
      <button class="btn" id="btn_filter_submit" onclick="show_report_data();">Go</button>
      <button class="btn" id="btn_filter_submit" onclick="show_reset_data();">Clear</button>
    </div>
</div>

 using multiple try javascript code but not apply any changes

<script src="{{asset('assets/js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
<script>
  function show_reset_data() {
    $("reset").each(function() { this.selectedIndex = 0 });
}
function show_reset_data() {
  document.getElementById("reset").reset();
}
function show_reset_data() {
  document.getElementById("reset").value="";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I inserted class="reset" in each selected field means input field and button clear Id="reset" create and simple write javascript code.

<div style="margin-top:2%;display:none; " id="filt_box">    
    
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
        <label for="filter_seller_user">Sellers</label>
        <select class="form-control-dropdown reset" id="filter_seller_user" name="filter_seller_user[]" multiple="multiple">           
          @foreach($seller_user as $key=>$value)
            <option style = "font-size:13px;" value="{{$value->id}}">{{$value->name}}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
        <label for="filter_generated_by_user">Generated By</label>
        <select class="form-control-dropdown reset" id="filter_generated_by_user" name="filter_generated_by_user[]" multiple="multiple">
          @foreach($clients_user as $key=>$value)
            <option style = "font-size:13px;" value="clients_user-{{$value->id}}">{{$value->name}}</option>
          @endforeach
          @foreach($main_clients_user as $key=>$value)
            <option style = "font-size:13px;" value="main_clients_user-{{$value->id}}">{{$value->name}}</option>
          @endforeach
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
        <label for="filter_generated_by_user">Business Name</label>
        <input type="tetx" name="filter_business_name" id="filter_business_name" class="form-control reset">
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12 div_btn">
      <div id="err_date" class="text-danger"></div>
      <button class="btn" id="btn_filter_submit" onclick="show_report_data();">Go</button>
      <button class="btn" id="reset" style="background-color: #ae3029; color:white;">Clear</button>
    </div>


javascript code

$("#reset").on('click', function () {
    $('.reset').val('');
  });
```